# to solve a integration

Tags: integration

We have to find the value of following integration . I tried a lot , doing many substitution . But got no result pleas help q.[image]

Comment: You've been a member here long enough to know how the site works. Details of what you have tried is important. Then others will better understand where you are stuck and where you need help.

Comment: @IanMiller but As I said  I tried to do some substitution , but nothing I have got.

Comment: Next time, things like, what did you substitute and state why you didn't think that worked. Give us something to work with. Otherwise it looks like you are just looking for someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: @IanMiller sorry I will not do it again

Comment: I wasn't meaning to sound like I'm telling you off. Just teaching you how to ask better questions. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very good question . But at last I have solved this. [image]

Comment: +1  Integration by parts.  A more elementary solution, since you do not need to know about beta and gamma functions.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
I_{1} &= \int\limits_{0}^{1} (1-x^{50})^{100} dx \\
&= \frac{1}{50} \int\limits_{0}^{1} (1-y)^{100} y^{\frac{1}{50}-1} dy \\
&= \frac{1}{50} \mathrm{B}\left(101, \frac{1}{50}\right)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
I_{2} &= \int\limits_{0}^{1} (1-x^{50})^{101} dx \\
&= \frac{1}{50} \int\limits_{0}^{1} (1-y)^{101} y^{\frac{1}{50}-1} dy \\
&= \frac{1}{50} \mathrm{B}\left(102, \frac{1}{50}\right)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
5050\frac{I_{1}}{I_{2}} &= 5050 \frac{\mathrm{B}(101,1/50)}{\mathrm{B}(102,1/50)} \\
&= 5050 \frac{\Gamma(101)\Gamma(1/50)\Gamma(102+1/50)}{\Gamma(102)\Gamma(1/50)\Gamma(101+1/50)} \\
&= 5050 \frac{1}{101} (101 + 1/50) \\
&= 5051
\end{align}

Notes:

1.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Gamma(101)}{\Gamma(102)} = \frac{100!}{101!} = \frac{1}{101}
\end{equation}

2.
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(102+1/50) = \Gamma([101+1/50] + 1) = (101+1/50)\Gamma(101+1/50)
\end{equation}